# query taking too long to execute from plsql block

Tags: oracle, plsql

This query when executed alone it takes 1 second to executed when the same query is executed through procedure it is taking 20 seconds, please help me on this

```
SELECT * FROM
     (SELECT TAB1.*,ROWNUM ROWNUMM FROM
       (SELECT wh.workitem_id, wh.workitem_priority, wh.workitem_type_id, wt.workitem_type_nm,
          wh.workitem_status_id, ws.workitem_status_nm, wh.analyst_group_id,
          ag.analyst_group_nm, wh.owner_uuid, earnings_estimate.pr_get_name_from_uuid(owner_uuid) owner_name,
          wh.create_user_id, earnings_estimate.pr_get_name_from_uuid( wh.create_user_id) create_name, wh.create_ts,
          wh.update_user_id,earnings_estimate.pr_get_name_from_uuid(wh.update_user_id) update_name, wh.update_ts, wh.bb_ticker_id, wh.node_id,
          wh.eqcv_analyst_uuid, earnings_estimate.pr_get_name_from_uuid( wh.eqcv_analyst_uuid) eqcv_analyst_name,
          WH.WORKITEM_NOTE,Wh.PACKAGE_ID ,Wh.COVERAGE_STATUS_NUM ,CS.COVERAGE_STATUS_CD ,Wh.COVERAGE_REC_NUM,I.INDUSTRY_CD INDUSTRY_CODE,I.INDUSTRY_NM
INDUSTRY_NAME,WOT.WORKITEM_OUTLIER_TYPE_NM  as WORKITEM_SUBTYPE_NM
          ,count(1) over() AS total_count,bro.BB_ID BROKER_BB_ID,bro.BROKER_NM BROKER_NAME, wh.assigned_analyst_uuid,earnings_estimate.pr_get_name_from_uuid(wh.assigned_analyst_uuid)
assigned_analyst_name
     FROM earnings_estimate.workitem_type wt,
          earnings_estimate.workitem_status ws,
          earnings_estimate.workitem_outlier_type wot,
          (SELECT * FROM (
               SELECT  WH.ASSIGNED_ANALYST_UUID,WH.DEFERRED_TO_DT,WH.WORKITEM_NOTE,WH.UPDATE_USER_ID,EARNINGS_ESTIMATE.PR_GET_NAME_FROM_UUID(WH.UPDATE_USER_ID)
UPDATE_NAME, WH.UPDATE_TS,WH.OWNER_UUID, EARNINGS_ESTIMATE.PR_GET_NAME_FROM_UUID(OWNER_UUID)
OWNER_NAME,WH.ANALYST_GROUP_ID,WH.WORKITEM_STATUS_ID,WH.WORKITEM_PRIORITY,EARNINGS_ESTIMATE.PR_GET_NAME_FROM_UUID( WI.CREATE_USER_ID) CREATE_NAME, WI.CREATE_TS,
               wi.create_user_id,wi.workitem_type_id,wi.workitem_id,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY WH.WORKITEM_ID ORDER BY WH.CREATE_TS DESC NULLS LAST, ROWNUM) R,
               wo.bb_ticker_id, wo.node_id,wo.eqcv_analyst_uuid,
               WO.PACKAGE_ID ,WO.COVERAGE_STATUS_NUM ,WO.COVERAGE_REC_NUM,
               wo.workitem_outlier_type_id                             
                     FROM earnings_estimate.workitem_history wh
                     JOIN EARNINGS_ESTIMATE.workitem_outlier wo
                     ON wh.workitem_id=wo.workitem_id
                     JOIN earnings_estimate.workitem wi
                     ON wi.workitem_id=wo.workitem_id
                     AND WI.WORKITEM_TYPE_ID=3
                     and wh.workitem_status_id not in (1,7)
                    WHERE ( wo.bb_ticker_id IN (SELECT  
                           column_value from table(v_tickerlist)  )
            )
      )wh
                       where r=1
                    AND DECODE(V_DATE_TYPE,'CreatedDate',WH.CREATE_TS,'LastModifiedDate',WH.UPDATE_TS) >= V_START_DATE
                    AND decode(v_date_type,'CreatedDate',wh.create_ts,'LastModifiedDate',wh.update_ts) <= v_end_date
                    and decode(wh.owner_uuid,null,-1,wh.owner_uuid)=decode(v_analyst_id,null,decode(wh.owner_uuid,null,-1,wh.owner_uuid),v_analyst_id)
                    ) wh,
          earnings_estimate.analyst_group ag,
          earnings_estimate.coverage_status cs,
          earnings_estimate.research_document rd,
         ( SELECT
             BB.BB_ID ,
              BRK.BROKER_ID,
              BRK.BROKER_NM
          FROM EARNINGS_ESTIMATE.BROKER BRK,COMMON.BB_ID BB
          WHERE  BRK.ORG_ID = BB.ORG_ID
          AND BRK.ORG_LOC_REC_NUM = BB.ORG_LOC_REC_NUM
          AND BRK.primary_broker_ind='Y') bro,
          earnings_estimate.industry i
     WHERE  wh.analyst_group_id = ag.analyst_group_id
      AND wh.workitem_status_id = ws.workitem_status_id
      AND wh.workitem_type_id = wt.workitem_type_id
      AND wh.coverage_status_num=cs.coverage_status_num
      AND wh.workitem_outlier_type_id=wot.workitem_outlier_type_id
      AND wh.PACKAGE_ID=rd.PACKAGE_ID(+)
      AND rd.industry_id=i.industry_id(+)
      AND rd.BROKER_BB_ID=bro.BB_ID(+)
      ORDER BY wh.create_ts)tab1 )
      ;
```

Comment: 1) Avoid using old style joins (they are usually less efficient **AND** not everybody knows and understands them.  
2) Simplify your query - it is too big to read, in the process of simplification you are likely to find your problem.  
3) sub-selects are **NEVER** good for performance

Comment: when you say executed alone, what do you mean? in a GUI, or sqlplus? also if you're running it on a GUI, are you scrolling to the last row and not just seeing the time for 1 "page" of results to come back? do this in sqlplus `set autotrace traceonly`
`set timing on`
`(run your select)`
and paste the output in your question.

Comment: executed in sqlplus it is having only two rows as result

Comment: old style joins are not less efficient at all. ANSI joins certainly have some advantages (seprating joins from filters and allowing more complex outer joining and more readbility) but they are processed in the same way by the SQL Engine (barring bugs). and "sub-selects are NEVER good for performance" is an absurd generalisation and not true at all for Oracle.

Comment: wo.bb_ticker_id IN (SELECT  
                           column_value from table(v_tickerlist)  )
I think this statement is creating problem when hardcoded like wo.bb_ticker_id IN ('888 yu') it is giving result in one second via procedure.but when passed as an input to the procedure it is taking time.

Comment: Note that count(1) should be count(*)

Comment: I believe count(1) vs. count(*) will make no difference here.

Comment: How are you executing this query in your procedure? Obviously, there has to be more wrapped around it. At the very least there has to be an INTO clause somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the problem is most likely related to `SELECT column_value from table(v_tickerlist)`.

By default, Oracle estimates that table functions return 8168 rows.  Since you're testing the query with a single value, I assume that the actual number of values is usually much smaller.  Cardinality estimates, like any forecast, are always wrong.  But they should at least be in the ballpark of the actual cardinality for the optimizer to do its job properly.

You can force Oracle to always check the size with dynamic sampling.  This will require more time to generate the plan, but it will probably be worth it in this case.

For example:

```
SQL> --Sample type
SQL> create or replace type v_tickerlist is table of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> --Show explain plans
SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain;
SQL> --Default estimate is poor.  8168 estimated, versus 3 actual.
SQL> SELECT column_value from table(v_tickerlist(1,2,3));

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1748000095

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |      |  8168 | 16336 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      |  8168 | 16336 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL> --Estimate is perfect when dynamic sampling is used.
SQL> SELECT /*+ dynamic_sampling(tickerlist, 2) */ column_value
  2  from table(v_tickerlist(1,2,3)) tickerlist;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1748000095

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |      |     3 |     6 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      |     3 |     6 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)

SQL>
```

If that doesn't help, look at your explain plan (and post it here).  Find where the cardinality estimate is most wrong, then try to figure out why that is.

Answer (score -2):

Your query is too big and will take time when executing on bulk data. Try putting few de-normalised temp tables, extract the data there and then join between the temp tables. That will increase the performance.

With this stand alone query, do not pass any variable inside the subqueries as in the below line...

> WHERE ( wo.bb_ticker_id IN (SELECT
>                              column_value from table(v_tickerlist)

Also, the outer joins will toss the performance.. Better to implement the denormalised temp tables

Comment: The size of the query text will make no difference on performance. Personally, I think making temp tables to optimize one particular query is not a good approach.